# Connect-PnPOnline Unsupported user type 'Unknown'

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2016

I have installed SharePointPnPPowershell on my dev machine which is running SP2016.

I tried to connected to my local sharepoint site using:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "http//....:7999" -Credentials (Get-Credential)
```

but I a getting the following error:

```
cmdlet Get-Credential pipeline position 1
Supply values for the follwoing parameters:
Credential
Connected-PnPPoline: Unsupported user type 'unknown'. Please see https//aka.ms...
```

I don't know if proxy has anything to do with this.
Can anyone help please?